# AngularJS - How to access Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Javascript Array which holds values. I want that Array to be the source that Angular reads off to update the UI. But i how do i access it from Angular?

Like:

```
<script>
var myArr = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];
/**
 * then all Angular stuffs here...
 */
</script>

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in what?">
           {{ i }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Of course i can build an Array in Angular scope. But anyway, how do i access the `Javascript Array` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Global Variable in Angular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749034/call-global-variable-in-angular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

> I have an Javascript Array which holds values. I want that Array to be
>   the source that Angular reads off to update the UI.

Well, you <strike>cannot</strike> *should not*. You should move that in your angularjs controller. Thats because anything you write within `<script>` tag would be out of angular's context.

Simply move the array to controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myArr = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];
});
```

**UPDATE:** [After discussion with @Cerbrus in comments below]

As answered by @deceze and @Amir, its *doable* by injecting the `$window` service in controller and creating a similar array in *angular's context*. Also, just because something is doable doesnt mean you should go for it.

```
function($scope, $window) {
   $scope.myArr = $window.myArr;
}
```

Comment: You _[can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31428312/1835379)._

Comment: @Cerbrus . Bud did you see the OP code? he had only script tag, he doe's not configure any angular basics. so I explained you can't.  That is wrong?

Comment: @RameshRajendran: He's saying the OP can't use that array he already has. That's simply not true, that specific array _can_ be used.

Comment: But @NLN answer was also correct

Comment: @RameshRajendran: No he's not. NLN is saying you can _only_ use arrays in the controller, but you _can also_ access global arrays from the `$window` object. He's saying it's not possible while it is.

Comment: @Cerbrus . Okay I agree with you. But tell me a solution for if I using Same array name(myArr ) in different js file, then how can i get the array (myArr ) in mycontroller??? if we use angular array, then that is a better way to js array

Comment: That's not what's happening here, but that's the reason coding like the OP does is a bad practice, and ___that___ is what you should explain in an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Updated the answer. Thanks for the constructive criticism :)

Comment: okay cool. The OP does dot explain well, we have answering by OP code. That's all buddy... forgive me, If my explanation is wrong. :)

Comment: @NLN: That is way better!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the var is on the window (got if from an external source), you can inject `$window` to your controller and fetch it.

// Controller

```
function($scope, $window) {
   $scope.myArr = $window.myArr;
}
```

// View:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in myArr">
            {{ i }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hor0vdug/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variable on the `$scope` on the associated controller. If the array comes from "outside" Angular, simply do this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.myArr = $window.myArr;
});
```

Now `myArr` is available in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

But If you want to do this, ***you need configure lot of things***...

.... Call angular scripts

..... route specifications

..... learned about MVC architecture with using angular.js

.....  And angular variables

So please Learn [here](https://angularjs.org/#)

Read this [article](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc)

Comment: You _[can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31428312/1835379)._

Comment: @Cerbrus . Bud did you see the OP code? he had only script tag, he doe's not configure any angular basics. so I explained you can't.  That is wrong?

Comment: You're saying the OP can't use that array he already has. That's simply not true, that specific array _can_ be used.

Comment: I have answered for only him code, he does not explained which he have configured angular.js . That's why me and some other post a answer for this type

Comment: Your answer is telling the OP he needs to set up routing and learn about MVC, too. Both are not true.

Comment: I agree with @RameshRajendran. Also, just because something is *doable* doesnt mean it is a good practice

Comment: If it's a bad practice, _explain that it is_. But don't tell people something isn't possible when it clearly is.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `myArr` to $scope instead of `var myArr.`

Replace  `var myArr` to `$scope.myArr` and put it inside the controller.Simple as it is

Comment: Without a controller, that's not going to work.

Comment: Of Course .You need a controlller